# Displaying an action sheet over a disabled tab bar in tab bar partially enables it

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I think I found a bug in UIKit, but first I want to be sure I'm not insane.

I have a tab bar with a disabled tabBarItem in it. If I present an action sheet from the tab bar, then cancel/press any button in it, after the action sheet dismisses the tab bar item *appears* enabled, but cannot be clicked.

I want it to stay disabled.

I uploaded an [example project here](https://github.com/kevinbarrett/action-sheet-plus-tab-bar). Run it in the simulator and press the action sheet button on the first view controller. Note the state of the second tab bar item before and after the sheet appears. The project itself is a standard "Tabbed Application" template with one tab item disabled and an IBAction for the button added.

Is this a bug, or am I misusing the APIs?

Comment: Umm, there is no "action sheet button" in any of the view controllers.. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @kevboh in the repository you linked there is only the standard tabbed application template, no buttons except the ones on the tab bar.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Let me update it...

Comment: A strange bug indeed. It seems like the problem is with `showWithTabBar:`. At least the bug does not occur if `showInView:` is used.

Comment: @matsr but in a setup with tab bar showInView: has a well-known issue of bottom area of the action sheet (usually bottom half of the Cancel button) being not responsive to touches

Comment: @MaxO yep, that's true. The area that is covered by the tabBar seems to be the problem. The folks at Apple obviously have some bugfixes to do. :-)

Comment: Filed: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1818402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug it is...

As a quick and safe workaround add this to the view controller (assuming it will be an UIActionSheet's delegate)

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    for (UITabBarItem *item in self.tabBarController.tabBar.items) {
        item.enabled = !item.enabled;
        item.enabled = !item.enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever. Sucks that I have to do that in every action sheet callback, though.

Comment: If you are using some kind of a block-based UIActionSheet helper (like [this](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-block-based-uialertview-and-uiactionsheet/) - though last time I checked it need some fixes/updated) you can easily extended it to automatically fix buttons when displayed from the tab bar

Comment: Yeah, I'm not. What would be awesome is if there was a notification posted by `UIActionSheet` when it dismissed, but I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your Project and found a way to make it work. `But I don't know actually is it a bug or not.` I just find out, it is happening only when you show the `actionsheet` from the method using `showFromTabbar`: method.

```
[sheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

When i changed it to show in this view only, then its not changing the tabBarItem image.

```
[sheet showInView:self.view];
```

Hope this could help you to continue to work on that project.